# Updating model value in DOM event handler

Tags: angularjs

I have an input element which, on focus, I want to open a dialog which allows the user to perform a complicated selection, then return the result to the input field:

```
<input ng-model="vm.requestType" ng-focus="vm.getMessageType($event)">
<input ng-model="vm.responseType" ng-focus="vm.getMessageType($event)">
```

controller:

```
function getMessageType( event ) {

  $mdDialog.show( {
        controller : 'MessageTypeController',
        controllerAs : 'vm',
        templateUrl : 'html/message-type.html',
        locals : { type : event.target.value },
        bindToController: true
      } ).then( function( type ) {

      //  this updates the DOM, but not the model
      event.target.value = type;

      // this works, but does not allow
      // me to use this function generically for 
      // several different model fields

      vm.requestType = type;

      }, function( fail ) {
  });
}
```

It works great, but it only updates the view, not the model. If I update the model value directly, it works, but I can't use the handler for multiple `<input>`s.

How can I update the model value associated with the `<input>` form element from within an event handler?

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution. The trick is to get a hold of the controller, then use $setViewValue and $render();

```
<input ng-model="vm.requestType" ng-focus="vm.getMessageType($event)">
<input ng-model="vm.responseType" ng-focus="vm.getMessageType($event)">

  var controller = angular.element( event.srcElement ).controller( 'ngModel' );

  $mdDialog.show( {
    controller : 'MessageTypeController',
    controllerAs : 'vm',
    templateUrl : 'html/message-type.html',
    locals : { type : event.target.value },
    bindToController: true
  }).then( function( type ) {

    controller.$setViewValue( type );
    controller.$render();

  }, function( fail ) {

  });
```

This can also be implemented as a directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive( 'selectType', [ '$mdDialog', function( $mdDialog ) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function( scope, element, attributes, controller ) {

      element.bind( 'focus', function() {
        $mdDialog.show( {
          controller : 'MessageTypeController',
          controllerAs : 'vm',
          templateUrl : 'html/message-type.html',
          locals : { type : controller.$modelValue },
          bindToController: true
        }).then( function( type ) {

          controller.$setViewValue( type );
          controller.$render();

        }, function( fail ) {
        });

      });
    }
  };
}]);
```